# calling a method from another window form closing event. c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, window

How can i call method of a window form from another form closing event ?
Suppose second for is getting closed and i want to call method of first form when second get closed to update some changes on first window form.

Comment: Did you try something? You open the second form with `Show` or `ShowDialog` method?

Answer (score 5):

You can add an event handler to the `form_closing` event in the first form and handle it accordingly.

Somewhere in `form1`

```
form2.Form_Closing += yourhandler;
```

Comment: no actually i am trying to call call method of first form when second form will get closed.

Comment: @AmritPal Which is *exactly* what this does.

Comment: @AmritPal Steve's solution will work.  If you place the above code in the first form it will be called when the second form closes

Comment: @AmritPal the form_closing event will fire when the 2nd form is closing, so if you listen to the event in the first form, the event handler method will get called whenever 2nd form is closing. In the event handler you can call whatever method to do the update that you want

Comment: thnku Steve, Your solution work :)

Comment: Not working!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that form 2 has a a control called TextBox1, when form 2 closes the lambda expression will be called and transfer data to form 1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Form2 openedForm2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Not sure if you would want more than 1 form2 open at a time.
        if (this.openedForm2 == null)
        {
            this.openedForm2 = new Form2();
            //Here is your Event handler which accepts a Lambda Expression, code inside is performed when the form2 is closed.
            this.openedForm2.FormClosing += (o, form) =>
            {
                // this is Executed when form2 closes.
                // Gets text from Textbox1 on form2 and assigns its value to textbox1 on form 1
                this.textBox1.Text = ((Form2)o).Controls["TextBox1"].Text;
                // Set it null so you can open a new form2 if wanted.
                this.openedForm2 = null;
            };
            this.openedForm2.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            // Tells user form2 is already open and focus's it for them.
            MessageBox.Show("Form 2 is already open");
            this.openedForm2.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference from your first form to your second.  Say you create your second form this way (From your first form):

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.referenceToFirstForm = this
```

In your second form you should have this:

```
public Form1 referenceToFirstForm
```

Then in your `OnClosing` event you can reference `referenceToFirstForm`

Comment: Why go through all that extra work, greatly increase the coupling of your forms, add in the extra fragility, when you could just use events properly and attach the event from where it should be handled, rather than from within the class that defines it.

Comment: Just providing options. Steve's solution is better.